# Sumar valores de un array JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Tengo este array JSON:

```
[{"amount":"500"},{"amount":"750"},{"amount":"250"}]
```

He intentado sumar los valores que contiene con:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.com..../water.php',function(data_water_tot){
console.log(data_water_tot);
 $.each(data_water_tot,function(){
    total += data_water_tot[cont].amount;
 });
 console.log(total);
});
```

No se como hacer para sumar 400+750+250.

Comment: No falta comilla, se cierra debajo de todo el getJSON, pero gracias.

Comment: Tienes que usar parseInt(data_water_tot[cont].amount) lo está tomando como string es por eso que te concatena el resultado en lugar de sumarlo.

Comment: El json te llega como respuesta de una petición AJAX? si es asi te puedo ayudar es muy sencillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto el problema, así, por si a alguien le interesa:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.com..../water.php',function(data_water_tot){
    cont=0;
    total=0;
    console.log(data_water_tot);
     $.each(data_water_tot,function(){
        valor = parseInt(data_water_tot[cont].amount);
        cont++;
        total = total+valor;
     });
     console.log(total); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No te suma porque no tienes una variable `cont` dentro del each, te sugiero hacer estos cambios en la función del `.each()`:

```
function(pos, elemento){
  total += elemento.amount;
}
```

la variable `pos` es un indice de la posición del arreglo, `elemento` es el objeto que se encuentra en una posición del arreglo, el cual ya no es necesario tener el arreglo e indicar la posición a consultar.

Te debería quedar de esta forma:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.com..../water.php',function(data_water_tot){
  console.log(data_water_tot);
  $.each(data_water_tot,function(pos, elemento){
    total += elemento.amount;
  });
  console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto de otra forma. Pero gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @KikuS. He visto tu respuesta, es valida, pero si te quieres ahorrar lineas la forma que te expongo es lo mismo que haces tú, te evitas estar aumentando la variable `cont` en cada repetición, en ese caso seria mejor usar un `for`. haz la prueba y comprobaras a que me refiero. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Los arreglos en JavaScript tienen​ el método `forEach`, que aceptan como argumento cada valor del arreglo. Dentro de cada llamada, se puede sumar el valor de cada ítem.

```js
data_water_tot = [{"amount":"500"},{"amount":"750"},{"amount":"250"}];
console.log(data_water_tot);
var total = 0;
data_water_tot.forEach(function (obj) {
    total += parseInt(obj.amount);
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una descripción, al menos breve, de por cómo es que este código real responde a la pregunta?

Comment: puedes ver los resultados dandole click a ejecutar

Comment: los arreglos en javascript tiene el metodo forEach, que aceptan como argumento cada valor del arreglo